# UITableView - how do I hide the edit button?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uistoryboard

I've created a master detail app using the template in Xcode.  When I did the Apple ToDoList tutorial where you start with an ordinary app and add the second view yourself I added the plus and done buttons, but this template seems to include them automatically, except that I don't see them in interface builder, only when I run the app.  I don't want to have an "edit" button on the top left (although I do want users to be able to swipe to delete items).

So, my question is twofold:

1. Why does the Master Detail app template include edit and + buttons
   which don't show up in the storyboard (see screenshots) and
2. How do I get rid of that Edit button (while leaving the
   swipe-to-delete
       functionality)?

http://www.mazz0.com/images/xcode/masterdetaileditbutton/storyboard.png
http://www.mazz0.com/images/xcode/masterdetaileditbutton/app.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove it easily with:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.I'm not at my workstation at the mo - should I expect to find that line included in the template (but with something other than nil), or will that be up in one of the superclasses?  The reason I'm asking is that I'd rather remove it from the code altogether and set it in the Interface Builder if possible.

Comment: Yes you can remove everything in `viewDidLoad` appart from `[super viewDidLoad];`. You can also delete: `- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender`.

Answer (score 0):

In your `TableViewController` you can comment out:

```
// Use the edit button item provided by the table view controller.
// navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem()
```

Comment: put 4 white-spaces before every code line and add few explanation as well.